# Invalid DateTime format after website publish on IIS

Tags: datetime-format

I know there are numerous posts on this issue but none worked for me and hence I thought to post one by myself. I hope I am not spamming.

All I want to do is to convert string into a DateTime object. It worked fine on VS Web Develpoment Server but when I published it to IIS it started throwing the exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I went through numerous posts and tried following code but they all failed. For simplicity I hard coaded the DateTime string. Please note, format of DateTime in the string is fixed, I have to use that only.

```
Convert.ToDateTime("27-6-2012 9:05 PM")

// Just for the sake of it I also used CurrentUICulture and InstalledUICulture in the line below.
// Note: For me CurrentCulture = CurrentUICulture = InstalledUICulture = en-US
Convert.ToDateTime("27-6-2012 9:05 PM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

DateTime.Parse("27-6-2012 9:05 PM")

// Just for the sake of it I also used CurrentUICulture and InstalledUICulture in the line below.
// Note: For me CurrentCulture = CurrentUICulture = InstalledUICulture = en-US
DateTime.Parse("27-6-2012 9:05 PM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

// Just for the sake of it I also used CurrentUICulture and InstalledUICulture in the line below.
// Note: For me CurrentCulture = CurrentUICulture = InstalledUICulture = en-US
DateTime.ParseExact("27-6-2012 9:05 PM", "{0:d-M-yyyy h:mm tt}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Then just for experinment I changed format of the date in string to "6/27/2012 9:05 PM". I found all of the above worked except DateTime.ParseExact. For me if any one of the above codes work, I am good but the problem is that I cannot change the format of date in the string, that comes as a parameter which is not in my control.

This looks like such a trivial issue but I don't know what is it that I am missing? It is so embarrassing. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the regional settings on the server are not the same as on your dev environment. Try this. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241671

EDIT - Look in control panel under the regional settings. This will effect how the server reads dates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had come to this post earlier but the problem is that when my application goes on production I will not be allowed to make these changes.

Comment: Just for the info, I even changed the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture of the web app on IIS to en-US. This too did not help. In the code though, when I debug, it is still showing all cultures as en-US. Don't know what is going wrong!!

Comment: I just now tried the above date settings change. Still the same problem. As mentioned in my post, if I change format of the Date in string to "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt" i.e. if I use "6/27/2012 9:05 PM" in my example then things are good. I just thought to bring this point to light!

Comment: This worked,

DateTime.ParseExact("27-6-2012 9:05 PM", "d-M-yyyy h:mm tt", null)